How to reject same filename and ask the user to rename the file using upload class in codeigniter,?
I am creating an upload form using codeiginiter upload class to facilitate user uploading file (allowed .csv only). I want to force the users renaming their filename before they upload the csv by rejecting them if the filename is same.
$folder is my path (correctly set as I can retrieve the file and presented on another page);
$config['file_name'] is formed to >strtolower($_FILES[$field_name]['name']); resulting uploaded_user_file_name.csv as expected.
I set >$config['overwrite'] = TRUE; to avoid appending increment num at the end of filename.
if(file_exists($folder.'/'.$config['file_name'])) 
   {
        //$status['status'] = 0;
        $message = 'Please rename your file';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', $message );
        redirect('pengumuman-new', 'refresh');
   }else{
    //proceed to upload

   }

HOWEVER, the code above resulting in processing the upload and overwriting the file.
Please help.
I had tried setting >$config['overwrite'] = FALSE; but it is not working.
I tried modifying the path (in case I mistakenly wrote the wrong path) but no solution too.

A better solution would be to allocate a unique random filename to the uploaded file that you store on your server, and record the original file name and the new filename in the database as part of the users' records. You might need a new table for that. That avoids filename conflicts by a single user, and between users.

The problem is not whether the filename is conflict or no. But, it seems that my code using file_exist function is not working. But, when I turn $config['overwrite'] = false, file_exist works fine, proven by appending increment number at the end of the same filename.

For unique file name you can append timestamp.,so that file name will be unique,no need to update in settings.
